# How do I access the data in the .pre('validation') hook?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am having trouble with performing operations during the pre('validate') hook. I need to do some prevalidation (making sure at least one of 2 different fields is populated, but not necessarily both, for example).

```
const AccessorySchema = new Schema({
    accessory: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: [
            'Offense',
            'Defence',
            'Miscellaneous'
        ]
    },
    space: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        validate: {
            validator: Number.isInteger,
            message: 'Space must be an integer'
        }
    },
    priceFixed: {
        type: Number,
        required: false,
        validate: {
            validator: Number.isInteger,
            message: 'Fixed Price must be an integer'
        }
    },
    priceMultiplier: {
        type: [Schema.Types.Mixed],
        required: false
    },
    weightFixed: {
        type: Number,
        required: false,
        validate: {
            validator: Number.isInteger,
            message: 'Fixed Weight must be an integer'
        }
    },
    weightMultiplier: {
        type: [Schema.Types.Mixed],
        required: false
    },
    vehicles: {
        type: [String],
        required: true,
        enum: ["car","cycle"]
    }
});

AccessorySchema.pre('validate', (next) => {
    console.log(this);
    next();
});
```

And I send it this object :

```
{
    accessory: "some name",
    category: "Miscellaneous",
    priceMultiplier: [3,5],
    weightMultiplier:  [3,5],
    space: 0,
    vehicles: ["car"]
}
```

this logs `{}` and populates the mongo DB. But I can't check any of the properties in pre validation.

mongoose version is ^4.7.7, nodejs 6.10.2, mongodb version is 3.2.9

How can I access the data in the pre validation hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not use arrow function, it doesn't bind the context.
Change your code to below

```
AccessorySchema.pre('validate', function(next){
    console.log(this);
    next();
});
```